# I want to replace all dots with br except that dots between digits and after shortcut words

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace all dots with br except that dots between digits and after shortcut words.

for example:

```
this is my number 1.4 hi dr. david, my name is ayman. how are you. thanks you
```

converted to

```
this is my number 1.4 hi dr. david, my name is ayman <br /> how are you <br /> thanks
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Define "shortcut words".

Comment: like dr., Mr. , Congra. ...  I tried this.  preg_match('/(.*)\.([^.]*)$/', $content['contents'], $matches);

Comment: So what you are saying, is you want to split the strings at the end of logical sentences?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_boundary_disambiguation has a PHP code snippet. It is imperfect, but you can't get much better without dictionary and/or statistical methods.

Comment: yes i want to split the sentences at the end, so I expect the dot is the end of sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You can play a bit with negative [lookbehind/lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) expressions. For example

```
(?<!dr|mr|mrs|miss)\.(?!\d)
```